# Is there a Java JSON deserializer that decodes a string into dictionary of lists or lists of dictionaries of primitive types

Tags: java, json, primitive

I need to pull back from a database JSON documents that are not based on a standard object.

Is there a way using JAVA to "deserialize" these documents into Lists & Dictionaries of primitive objects (string, int, bool, etc...)

Any library that can do this in both directions? 
In other words I am looking for the Java counter part of System.Runtime.Serialization.Json

Comment: Yes. There are a number of libraries that do this (see http://json.org). Most deal with some "internal" objects which are the equivalent of `List` and `Map` to deal with the dynamic nature of the types in the structure more easily. (Dealing with `HashMap<String,Object>` is not very fun.)

Answer (score 5):

Rather than trying to force JSON into a difficult to use `Map<String, Object>` or `List<Object>`, I'd recommend a library that can parse JSON into a tree model. While many libraries can do this sort of thing, [Google Gson](http://google-gson.googlecode.com) is my favorite. You can use its `JsonParser` class to parse JSON as a tree starting with a root [JsonElement](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/JsonElement.html). Once you have the `JsonElement`, it should be considerably easier to use than some `Object` that might be a `List` and might be a `Map`.

```
JsonElement e = new JsonParser().parse(someJson);
if (e.isJsonObject()) {
  // JsonObject has many of the same methods as a Map
  JsonObject obj = e.getAsJsonObject();
  String foo = obj.get("foo").getAsString();
  int bar = obj.get("bar").getAsInt();
} else if (e.isJsonArray()) {
  JsonArray array = e.getAsJsonArray();
  // JsonArray implements Iterable and can be used a lot like a List
  for (JsonElement element : array) {
    ...
  }
}
```

It's easy to build a JSON tree using these objects as well.

Answer (score 5):

Almost every single Java library at http://json.org/ can do this, did you actually try finding something?

For example, with [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org) you would do:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Map<String,Object> map = mapper.readValue(json, Map.class);
```

but it is often convenient to create your own Java objects to map to; there is no need to use standard objects. For example:

```
  public class MyType {
    public String name;
    public int age;
    // and so on
    public Date createTime;
  }

  MyType instance = mapper.readValue(json, MyType.class);
```

For more examples, you can check out [Jackson tutorial](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes).

Answer (score 2):

Flexjson definitely does it. The below line de-serialize a jsonString to a HashMap

```
Map<String, String> map = new flexjson.JSONDeserializer().deserialize(jsonString);
```

Answer (score -3):

Sorry but JSON does not have any metainformation about datatypes, thus there is no chance to convert anything back not based on standard objects, except a list of strings.

**UPDATE:** I could think of making POGOs with Groovy out of a not classified JSON-String. Then you can also work with dynamic Objects. Maybe you can also utilize http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/.

Comment: I understand that JSON supports only a few types with no metainformation. What I need from a JSON string is just nested dictionaries and lists. I need the last level of nesting as strings preferably.

Comment: Downvoting without comment is rude. If something is wrong, first a hint should be given.

Comment: Your being voted down for giving incorrect advice. There are plenty of json libraries that can deserialize to to more complicated type definitions

Comment: Really. Which ones, without adding extra fields for metainformation? And in the end it comes to Strings, Numbers and Booleans and arrays of those. So deserializing Json is guessing about which type to deserialize.